# Webcomic: a zombie which uses a mask to live a normal life

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I read this web comic a really long time ago, here are the details I remember:

- The setting isn't post-apocalyptic, but rather "normal" with zombies being added to it
- IIRC, the story begins with no presentation and we start following the infected character immediately
- he lives a normal life, except he wears some kind of helmet / mask to avoid contaminating others
- the zombies aren't the stereotypical zombies you see in most media, however there are "outbreaks" which happen where some zombies act aggressively and bite/eat people
- society seems to not like zombies, or at least fear them. I think a seen in a public transport (bus? train?) references this
- the main character sees his own funeral that his family faked
- he lives with his family at the beginning, but I think he gets kidnapped by some mad doctor, who claims zombies are a panacea
- this same bad guy tries to sell something (a product or something like that, maybe the panacea?) to a client (I think she was female?)
- the main character somehow fights free of his captivity and the doctor dies killed by a female imprisoned zombie. I think there was some symbolic significance to his way of dying but I can't recall.
- at some point a female character is infected because a bullet hit her after hitting something infected (can't remember if it was another person that was bitten or a zombie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'm still rereading it and it seems I got a few details wrong, but here's the webcomic, *[Unlife](http://unlifecomic.com/2011/10/07/10072011/)*

- the setting isn't post-apocalyptic but seems to be moving towards one
- there is indeed outbreaks of zombies, but it seems to be the first or something like that
- people fear zombies (the bus scene is just one image however, not really part of the story for now)
- the story starts with the main character at his own funeral, but has some exposition too after a couple pages
- he lives with his family

I can't confirm everything else because I am not far enough.

I found it by typing word that relate to the comic in different search engines. I tried a lot of different combinations and at some point I landed on a review of it.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[No End](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/NoEnd)*? From [the webcomic's About page](https://noendcomic.com/about):

> No End is a webcomic about a group of people struggling to survive in a post apocalyptic country ravaged by an unyielding winter and hordes of undead. Living amid a world of horror doesn’t erase the cast’s day-to-day worries about identity, family, friendship and betrayal, as they seek people they can trust, as well a legendary place called “Haven” rumored to be free of the cold and horror.
>
> Just as none of them are sure that it even exists, they aren’t sure what their place in their world is. But each step forward leads towards who they are, who they should become, and where they belong.

[image: No End characters]

As you can see in the damage, Wight constantly wears a mask, although it sounds like it's more to cover up his lack of lips than to protect others.

Comment: Thanks, but the setting doesn't seem to match. The webcomic I'm looking for has the main character living a (sort of) normal day to day life. The setting isn't post-apocalyptic wasteland. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.